# Не работает поиск по Datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, sql-server

Здравствуйте, уважаемые! Помогите пожалуйста изгнать шайтана.. У меня почему то не работает поиск по Grid'у, если создаю отдельный проект, то все работает нормально, а если в существующем то ничего не происходит, вообще никакой реакции, привожу код:

Загрузка данных в Grid:

```
        SqlDataAdapter sqldataadapter;
        DataTable datatablesql;

        string tablename = textBox1.text;
        string sqlconnection = textBox2.text

        SqlConnection sqlconnect = new SqlConnection();
        sqlconnect.ConnectionString = sqlconnection;

        try
        {
            sqlconnect.Open();
            sqldataadapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM " + "[" + tablename + "]", sqlconnect);
            datatablesql = new DataTable();
            sqldataadapter.Fill(datatablesql);
            SqlDataPlacer.DataSource = datatablesql;                
            sqlconnect.Close();
            sqldataadapter.Dispose();
        }
        catch (SqlException sqlex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(sqlex.Message.ToString(), "Ошибка", MessageBoxButtons.OK);
        }
```

Поиск делаю так:

```
string search = searchbox.Text;

        for (int i = 0; i < SqlDataPlacer.Rows.Count - 1; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < SqlDataPlacer.Columns.Count - 1; j++)
            {
                if (SqlDataPlacer.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() == search)
                {
                    SqlDataPlacer.Rows[i].Selected = true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

И при этом ничего не происходит, ячейки в Grid'е могут заполняться не все, просто база может быть наполовину пуста и иметь такой вид:

[image: Скрин]

Когда делаю поиск, ничего не происходит. Может кто знает как правильно? И второй вопрос, можно ли при поиске выделять не полностью строку, а конкретную ячейку со значением?

А вот так все работает:

```
 private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable datatable = new DataTable();
        datatable.Columns.Add("One");
        datatable.Columns.Add("Two");
        datatable.Columns.Add("Three");
        datatable.Columns.Add("Four");

        for (int integer = 0; integer <= 50; integer++)
        {
            datatable.Rows.Add(integer, DateTime.Now, Application.CurrentCulture, Application.ExecutablePath);
        }

        dataGridView1.DataSource = datatable;
    }
```

я так полагаю, потому что Grid заполнен, могу ошибаться, нужна ваша помощь.

Comment: А вы не пробовали пройти код под отладчиком?

Comment: Пробовал, все нормально проходит, самое интересное событие поиска повешено на Text_Changed, так вот если вводишь, ноль реакции, а когда удаляешь искомый текст, в Grid'е выделяются все строки полностью

Comment: Подождите, а что именно идёт не так при поиске в `Text_Changed`? Можно там оттрассировать?

Comment: Что значит нормально проходит? Находится нужная строка? 
В строчку `SqlDataPlacer.Rows[i].Selected = true;` попадает отладчик?

Comment: Разобрался, поставил точку останова `SqlDataPlacer.Rows[i].Selected = true;` но до нее не доходит, если поставить здесь: `if (SqlDataPlacer.Rows[i].Cells[j].Value.ToString() == search)` то переменные в цикле `i,j` получают значение `0`.

Comment: Еще есть подозрение на то, что `DataTable = null`: http://s7.hostingkartinok.com/uploads/images/2015/05/8ce28b53e3c4f637f9b49cd58c649eba.png